# C# Linq Joining with AND conditions

Tags: c#, sql, linq, linq-to-sql, ssms

I am trying to figure on how to include a `AND` condition in my `Linq2SQL` statement

So my SQL as it looks in SSMS

```
SELECT TBL1.Field1, TBL2.Field2 FROM TABLE1 AS TBL1
INNER JOIN TABLE2 AS TBL2 ON TBL1.TBL2ID = TBL2.ID 
INNER JOIN TABLE3 AS TBL3 ON TBL1.TBL3ID = TBL3.ID AND TBL3.SQID = 20
WHERE TBL1.ID = 3
```

And my LINQ looks as follows

```
var linq = (from tbl1 in Table1
            join tbl2 in Table2 on tbl1.tabl2ID equals tbl2.ID
            join tbl3 in Table3 on tbl1.tabl3ID equals tbl3.ID
            where tbl1.ID = 3
            select new { field1 = tbl1.field1, field2 = tbl2.field2 
            }).ToList();
```

So how can I use a `AND` in my second join for `tbl3`? Any suggestions please?

Answer (score 0):

Just put extra where clause. `tbl3.SQID == 20`

```
var linq = (from tbl1 in Table1
            join tbl2 in Table2 on tbl1.tabl2ID equals tbl2.ID
            join tbl3 in Table3 on tbl1.tabl3ID equals tbl3.ID
            where tbl1.ID == 3 && tbl3.SQID == 20
            select new { field1 = tbl1.field1, field2 = tbl2.field2 
            }).ToList();
```

Comment: You can actually join with multiple conditions using `join tbl3 in Table3 on new { TBLID = tbl1.tabl3ID, SQID = tbl3.SQID }  equals new  { TBLID = tbl3.ID, SQID = 20 }`

Comment: There is no difference for this case.

Comment: In this case - yes, there is no difference, however, there is difference between `where` clause and `on` clause.

Comment: Of course, I mentioned it for this case.

Comment: Correct, but first of all OP was asking about `AND inside LINQ join`, second you don't know was that example a real project example, or was written for sake of example.